# Normal current flow in LSF010x level translators

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, level-shifting, level-translation

I am reviewing the datasheet and design documents for a level translator. TI has a great video explaining the operation of this device. I understand how the device works but my only concern is with current flowing into my lower voltage side source.
[image]

The video points out that under normal operation a few uA will flow into the VccA source. For my design, I have a TPS7A2025PDBVR linear voltage regulator (+2.5V). My higher side voltage is anywhere from +3.3V to +5.5V. I know that it is a only way street for a linear regulator and they cannot sink current, only source. But can it possibly sink this little? If not, how can I divert this current if it really is a problem? Or perhaps I should switch the linear regulator for a switching regulator just for the voltage translator?

In case you are curious, here is the full video:
https://training.ti.com/tlm-lsf-bias?context=1134826-1139264-1134790

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A switching regulator is not necessarily able to sink current.

In most cases, other devices connected to the 1.8 V supply will be able to eat that current. If not, you can simply add a resistor to ground.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing with the resistor but wasn't quite sure. But thank you for mentioning the other devices on the bus, this makes sense. I appreciate you response!